# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError error when using json.load

Tags: json

I am trying to load a JSON file, which is an export of data from another application, into Python in order to then parse out data within the file.  I am using json.load because this is a json type file.  However when I try and load this file I get an error of:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The file section of the file is {"version":"1.1.0","events":[{

this is the load code I am using:
with open(filename) as f:
data = json.load(f)

I tried the json.loads load but the I got a different error associated with the file begin a txt file type.  Any ideas?